# Syncfusion Blazor Grid within Splitter Drag and drop does not work correctly

Tags: blazor, drag-and-drop, syncfusion

There is a .Net Blazor Server application. I use two grids inside splitter panels. When trying to drag a record from one grid to another, the floating record disappears:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtEok.png)

While dragging:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVzsw.png)

Index.blazor:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<div>Horizontal Splitter</div>

<SfSplitter Height="500px" Width="100%">
    <SplitterPanes>
        <SplitterPane>
            <ContentTemplate>
                    <SfGrid TValue="Tmp"
                            ID="Grid1"
                            AllowSorting="true"
                            AllowSelection="true"
                            AllowFiltering="true"
                            FilterSettings="new GridFilterSettings{Type = Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.FilterType.Excel}"
                            DataSource="Src1"
                            Height="100%"
                            Toolbar="@(new List<object> {"Search"})"
                            AllowRowDragAndDrop="true">
                        <GridEditSettings AllowAdding="false"
                                          AllowDeleting="false"
                                          AllowEditing="false" />
                        <GridSelectionSettings Type="Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.SelectionType.Multiple" />
                        <GridRowDropSettings TargetID="Grid2" />
                        <GridEvents TValue="Tmp"
                                    RowDropped="@((e) => HandleRowDrop(e, "Grid1"))" />
                        <GridColumns>
                            <GridColumn Field="@($"{nameof(Tmp.Id)}")"
                                        HeaderText="Id"
                                        AutoFit="true"
                                        Visible="false"
                                        IsPrimaryKey="true" />
                            <GridColumn Field="@($"{nameof(Tmp.Name)}")"
                                        HeaderText="IP" />
                        </GridColumns>
                    </SfGrid>

            </ContentTemplate>
        </SplitterPane>
        <SplitterPane>
            <ContentTemplate>
                    <SfGrid TValue="Tmp"
                            ID="Grid2"
                            AllowSorting="true"
                            AllowSelection="true"
                            AllowFiltering="true"
                            FilterSettings="new GridFilterSettings{Type = Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.FilterType.Excel}"
                            DataSource="Src2"
                            Height="100%"
                            Toolbar="@(new List<object> {"Search"})"
                            AllowRowDragAndDrop="true">
                        <GridEditSettings AllowAdding="false"
                                          AllowDeleting="false"
                                          AllowEditing="false" />
                        <GridSelectionSettings Type="Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.SelectionType.Multiple" />
                        <GridRowDropSettings TargetID="Grid1" />
                        <GridEvents TValue="Tmp"
                                    RowDropped="@((e) => HandleRowDrop(e, "Grid1"))" />
                        <GridColumns>
                            <GridColumn Field="@($"{nameof(Tmp.Id)}")"
                                        HeaderText="Id"
                                        AutoFit="true"
                                        Visible="false"
                                        IsPrimaryKey="true" />
                            <GridColumn Field="@($"{nameof(Tmp.Name)}")"
                                        HeaderText="IP" />
                        </GridColumns>
                    </SfGrid>

            </ContentTemplate>
        </SplitterPane>
    </SplitterPanes>
</SfSplitter>

<style>
    .centered-content {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>

@code {
    private List<Tmp> Src1 { get; set; } = new List<Tmp>();
    private List<Tmp> Src2 { get; set; } = new List<Tmp>();
    private List<Tmp> Src3 { get; set; } = new List<Tmp>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await FillSrc();
    }

    private async Task FillSrc()
    {
        Src1 = Enumerable.Range(100, 5).Select(x => new Tmp()
            {
                Id = x,
                Name = "192.168.0." + x

            }).ToList();
        Src2 = Enumerable.Range(120, 5).Select(x => new Tmp()
            {
                Id = x,
                Name = "192.168.1." + x
            }).ToList();
        Src3 = Enumerable.Range(140, 5).Select(x => new Tmp()
            {
                Id = x,
                Name = "192.168.3." + x
            }).ToList();
    }

    private async Task HandleRowDrop(RowDroppedEventArgs<Tmp> arg, string target)
    {
    }

    public class Tmp
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I ask for help from the community.

I ask for help from the community.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, use the following CSS customization. Please refer to the code snippet and sample below for your reference.

```
<style>

.e-splitter.e-splitter-horizontal .e-pane.e-scrollable, .e-splitter.e-splitter-vertical .e-pane.e-scrollable{
    overflow:unset;
}
```

Sample Link:https://blazorplayground.syncfusion.com/embed/htVJtAXzAhOGiMMX?appbar=true&editor=true&result=true&errorlist=true&theme=bootstrap5

Comment: 2Prathap Senthil: more thanks